# How to find wrong order in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table with 2 columns:

`id (int not null, auto_incremented), and insert_date (date)`.

The table is filled sometimes from outside source where I don't have control over the data.

Time to time it happens that the id values are not in right order given by the date. How can I find these anomalities?

Example of wrong data:

```
1, 2014-02-03
2, 2014-02-01  <<<< WRONG! It should be between 2014-02-03 and 2014-02-04
3, 2014-02-04
4, 2014-02-04
5, 2014-03-01
```

Comment: What makes this "wrong"?  SQL engines generally don't guarantee storage order, except perhaps by the clustered index on the primary key.  You can order the results when *querying* the data, but why does the order matter for *storing* the data?

Comment: Why does it matter?  Let the database maintain your `primary key`, and if you need to have a `row number` in your results, you can easily create a `view`.

Comment: Can you create a trigger?

Comment: @sgeddes: both id and date data MUST TO BE aligned to each other, and the values are created outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  t1.*
FROM
  tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
  ON t1.id>t2.id
WHERE
  t1.datefield<t2.datefield
```

however, it is really not a problem to have dates in the "wrong" order since you can always order by the date column.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9021/1).

Comment: @Frantique what's the problem with real data? wrong result, or is it too slow?

Comment: No problem at all! :)

Comment: Grazie, @fthiella! :)